# Can DTLinitials access \fnames?

Tags: datatool

**Question UPDATED** with **MWE**

Using `datatool` to read a CSV file into LaTeX, I am able to obtain first names using `{\fnames=fnames}`, and then print using `\fnames`.

Sometimes, though, I would like to show initials instead of first names.

As the manual says, if I write `\DTLinitials{Mary}` that gives `M.`, I tried printing `\DTLinitials{\fnames}` instead of `\fnames` but that does not produce the initial letter when reading from a CSV file.

How can I pass the value of `\fnames` to `\DTLinitials`, please?
Is that actually possible?

I would appreciate your advice or help. Thank you.

Here is a MWE, the content of `folks.csv` file, and the error message that results when I try to use `\DTLinitials{\fnames}`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{members}{folks.csv}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\pagestyle{headings}


\DTLforeach{members}
{\fnames=fnames, \surname=surname}
{
\fnames\
\surname\

}

\end{document}
```

Content of `folks.csv`:

```
fnames,surname
Adam,Adamant
Diana,Duck
Flora,Flintstone
Walter,Mitty
Sally,Wallace
```

When Line 16 `\fnames\` is replaced by `\DTLinitials{\fnames}` the following error is produced:

> ERROR: Paragraph ended before \dtl@initialsnext was complete.
>
> --- TeX said ---  
>                      \par  l.19 }

Comment: @CarLaTeX --- I have updated my question with a MWE, the data file, and the error message which results when I try \DTLinitials{\fnames}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my [answer](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=110066#p110066) to your crosspost on [LaTeX.org](https://latex.org):

Expand `\fnames` before applying `\DTLinitials` to it. This can be done by using `\expandafter`, that temporarily skips the next control sequence:

```
\expandafter\DTLinitials\expandafter{\fnames}
```

[image: output]